# Reading POST data in php7

Tags: php, php-7

Submitting this form:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="test" value="0">
<input name="test[0].0" value="00">
<input name="test[0].1" value="01">
<input name="test[1].0" value="10">
<input name="test[1].1" value="11">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Results in:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "01"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
}
string(0) ""
```

How do I get the missing input values in php7 without changing the html code?

Comment: PHP 5 behaves the same. What do you expect? `test[0].0` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Without "multipart/form-data", I could parse it manually from "php://input" in php5 also from $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.
The POST data in this example is "test=0&test[0].0=00&test[0].1=01&test[1].0=10&test[1].1=11" which is submitted by the browser.

Comment: Please check the linked question and let me know if whether my solution works for you in PHP/7.

Comment: The HTML form is generated from a webserver I cannot change. Changing the content type in apache config is not possible, putting it in .htaccess does not seem to work.

Comment: @guest Did you try disabling `enable_post_data_reading`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Putting "php_value enable_post_data_reading 0" in .htaccess works, I did have to change some code.

Answer (score 3):

[`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) was **deprecated in `PHP 5.6`** and **removed completely in `PHP 7.0`**.

You have to change your html code.

```html
<input name="test[0][0]" value="00">
<input name="test[0][1]" value="01">
<input name="test[1][0]" value="10">
<input name="test[1][1]" value="11">
```

And then get them by

```php
$_POST['test'][0][0]
```